# How do I use UISearchController in iOS 8 where the UISearchBar is in my navigation bar and has scope buttons?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to use the new `UISearchController` from iOS 8, and embed its `UISearchBar` in my `UINavigationBar`. That's easily done as follows:

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.delegate = self
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```

But when I add the scope buttons:

```
searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Posts, Users, Subreddits"]
```

It adds the buttons behind the `UISearchBar` and obviously looks very odd.

How should I be doing this?

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems that UISearchController doesn't quite understand the idea of UISearchBar being inside the navbar. Even apple's example seem to put searchBar below the navbar.

Comment: which version your using it, this issue is there in beta 3 n 4.

Comment: If need follow this source link it should help   http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're bumping into a "design issue" where the `scopeBar` is expected to be hidden when the `searchController` is not active.

The scope bar buttons appear behind (underneath) the search bar since that's their location when the search bar becomes active and animates itself up into the navigation bar.

*When the search is not active, a visible scope bar would take up space on the screen, distract from the content, and confuse the user (since the scope buttons have no results to filter).*

Since your `searchBar` is already located in the titleView, the (navigation and search) bar animation that reveals the scope bar doesn't occur.

- The **easiest** option is to locate the search bar below the
  navigation bar, and let the `searchBar` animate up into the title
  area when activated. The navigation bar will animate its height,
  making room to include the scope bar that was hidden.  This will all
  be handled by the search controller.
- The second option, almost as easy, is to use a **Search** bar button
  icon, which will animate the `searchBar` and `scopeBar` down into
  view over the navigation bar.

  ```
  - (IBAction)searchButtonClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)__unused sender {
      self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
      self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
      self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
      self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
      self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
      self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"Posts", @"Users", @"Subreddits"];
      [self presentViewController:self.searchController animated:YES completion:nil];
  }
  ```
- If you want the `searchBar` to remain in the titleView, an animation
  to do what you want is not built in.  You'll have to roll your own
  code to handle the navigationBar height change and display your own
  scope bar (or hook into the internals, and animate the built-in
  `scopeBar` down and into view).

  If you're fortunate, someone else has written `willPresentSearchController:` code to handle the transition you want.
- If you want to always see a `searchBar` and `scopeBar`, you'll probably have to ditch using the built-in `scopeBar`, and replace it with a `UISegmentedControl` which the user will always see, even when the search controller is not active.

**Update:**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909956/4151918) suggested subclassing `UISearchController` to change its searchBar's height.

Comment: The second option is fantastic (esp, the `presentViewController` part for the searchController)