# How do I set the UISearchController's searchBar to a view that isn't the tableHeaderView or navigationItem.titleview?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to keep the search bar in view as the table scrolls. At the moment I'm placing it as the header in a tableview, and it works as it should, but of course the search bar scrolls off screen as you go down the table. I thought I could do this simply modifying this code sample:

[How do I use UISearchController in iOS 8 where the UISearchBar is in my navigation bar and has scope buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880031/how-do-i-use-uisearchcontroller-in-ios-8-where-the-uisearchbar-is-in-my-navigati)

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.delegate = self
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
tableview.tableHeaderView = searchContoller.searchBar // How to put it elsewhere?
//Alternative that also works
navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```

The idea was to take some other view and do

```
otherview = searchController.searchBar
```

For instance an outlet to a UISearchBar, or a blank UIView, or something like that.

But it doesn't show the searchBar if I do that. It seems to only work as the header view of a table or as a navigationItem.titleView.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you have a blank UIView place above the tableview, let's say you have an outlet to that blank UIView called `searchContainer`, then you can add the search bar to that view by `searchContainer.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)`

Comment: That's right! Add and answer and you'll score some more points.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you have a blank UIView that is placed above the tableview.

let's assume you have an outlet to that blank UIView called `searchContainer`.
Then you can add the search bar of the `UISearchController` to that view by adding the following line

```
searchContainer.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
```

Comment: it worked great for me to add the searchBar in the view controller, but the searchResultsController doesn't trigger each time I try to edit, just the first time.  But if I use a barButtonItem to launch the searchBar, the searchResultsController and the actual search triggers every time.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Occasionally you should setup your `viewDidLoad` method with `definesPresentationContext = true` and `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true` to prevent some layout misbehavior.

Comment: Is there a way to set the height and width of the searchController.searchBar before/after adding as subview?