# How to make a scopebar in UISearchController always visible in Ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I want to implement functionality in my `UISearchController`, with `ScopeBar`, where I don't want my scope bar to be hidden. I want it to always be visible and functional. Currently, it is visible on the first view load and then hides after search filter is applied. Then, going forward, it always becomes visible on a click of the search bar.

Comment: You may wish to include the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the Scope Bar to always be visible, you may want to hook up a separate UISegmentedControl and not use the Scope Bar at all so you do not have to mess around with UISearchController's default behavior.

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880031/how-do-i-use-uisearchcontroller-in-ios-8-where-the-uisearchbar-is-in-my-navigati) may help guide you to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true`

This worked for me. The spacing is a little funny, but it displays the scope bar before and while the searchController is active. Declared during viewDidLoad.