# How to make search bar not disappear while scrolling in table view?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I want to make my search bar stop scrolling along with table view. I tried to add search controller into `viewForHeaderInSection` and it failed.Also I want to try to show original content while search bar active. So I try to do it in `viewDidLoad` but I don't know how to make it work. Here is my code for both of method.

```
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Add both the table view and the search view into another view (which becomes the view of your view controller). Then the search view will be completely disconnected from your table view.

Note that if your view controller is currently a table view controller subclass you will need to change that to be a simple view controller subclass.

Comment: Do i need to all over again or just change tableViewcontoller class to ViewController class?

Comment: You can modify your existing controller class with protocol conformance, a property for the table and a new outlet connection...

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the searchbar to the header view. If you want to keep it above your table you can add it to the navigation controller view. [How do I use UISearchController in iOS 8 where the UISearchBar is in my navigation bar and has scope buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880031/how-do-i-use-uisearchcontroller-in-ios-8-where-the-uisearchbar-is-in-my-navigati)

Comment: Is any another way that not add search bar into navigation bar?