# Display searchController on buttonClick

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

i'm trying to show a searchController on buttonClick. However it seem to create an error when the button is clicked. I get an error on the `presentViewController` row. What am i doing wrong in order to achieve this?

by the way i'm having this code in a `tableViewController`

```
func searchButtonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self)
   // searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.presentViewController(self.searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: lldb error, can it be because i'm doing it in a UITableViewController?

Comment: I found a solution with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880031/how-do-i-use-uisearchcontroller-in-ios-8-where-the-uisearchbar-is-in-my-navigati