# Custom UISearchBar and UISearchController issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I would like to post a more specific question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904213/custom-uisearchbar-with-uisearchcontroller).

I implemented a custom `UISearchBar`, and thus a custom `UISearchController`, as this seemed to be the only solution to stop the search bar from displaying a Cancel button. This indeed solved the mentioned problem, but created a new one. For some reason, the `updateSearchResultsForSearchController:` delegate method (of the `viewController` where I have implemented the `searchController`) doesn't get called anymore (it does the first time I tap on the searchBar, but doesn't when the search string is being typed), while it does with a standard `UISearchController` and `UISearchBar`. As a result, the search results table **fails to appear** altogether.

Here is my code for `SearchBar.h`

```
@interface SearchBar : UISearchBar

@end
```

and `SearchBar.m`

```
#import "SearchBar.h"

@implementation SearchBar

- (void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton {
    // Do nothing...
}

- (void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // Do nothing....
}

@end
```

as well as `SearchController.h`

```
@interface SearchController : UISearchController

@end
```

and `SearchController.m`

```
#import "SearchController.h"
#import "SearchBar.h"

@interface SearchController () {
SearchBar *_searchBar;
}
@end

@implementation SearchController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (SearchBar *)searchBar {

    if (_searchBar == nil) {
        _searchBar = [[SearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    }
    return _searchBar;
}

@end
```

In MyViewController.h I subscribe to the following protocols:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating>
```

Can anyone see what I may have missed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28396967/3985749).  I think you need to ensure that the searchBar activates the Search Controller, perhaps in the `textDidChange:` searchBar delegate method.

Comment: If the only thing you want to do is to get rid of the “Cancel” button, why didn’t you just set the corresponding property on the `UISearchBar`?

Comment: Thanks @pbasdf, setting `self.searchController.active = YES` did it for me. However, differently from your linked answer, I set `MyViewController ` as the `searchBar.delegate` as I needed some other delegate performance in my view controller as well.

Comment: @Rafael, unfortunately, the property seems to do nothing, hence the workaround..